# How to remove redundant quotation marks in dynamically created json object with javascript?

Tags: javascript, regex, json, quotes

Following problem: I want to create an Audio player with a playlist like on this site: http://www.davidorlowsky.com/player/demos/lark.htm

If you click the right mouse button and view the source code you'll see that the playlist has the following form:

```
[
        {
            title:"Gypsy Hora",
            artist:"Trad.",
            mp3:"http:///www.klezmorim-online.de/lark/gypsyhora.mp3"
        },
        {
            title:"Sammy's Freilach",
            artist:"Trad.",
            mp3:"http:///www.klezmorim-online.de/lark/sammysfreilach.mp3"
        },
        ...
]
```

What I'm trying to do is: creating this kind of playlist dynamically via parsing through a directory. This is how I try to do it:

```
$(document).ready(function () {                
    var sound_files = Array();
    $.ajax({
        url: "my_directory/",
        success: function (data) {
            $(data).find("td > a").each(function () {
                var file = $(this).attr("href");
                if (file.substr((file.lastIndexOf('.') + 1)) == "mp3") {
                    var mp3 = file;
                    var title= mp3.substr(0, mp3.lastIndexOf('.'));
                    //sound_files.push("{title: \""+title+"\", mp3: \"my_directory/" + mp3 + "\"}");
                    sound_files.push("{mp3: \"my_directory/" + mp3 + "\"}");
                }
            });
        }
    }).done(function () {
        console.log(sound_files);
        new jPlayerPlaylist({
            jPlayer: "#jquery_jplayer_1",
            cssSelectorAncestor: "#jp_container_1"
        }, sound_files, {
            swfPath: "jplayer",
            supplied: "oga,mp3"
        });
    });
});
```

It doesn't work that way and I think it's because there are redundant quotation marks in the json object. The resulting object looks like this:

```
["{mp3: "my_directory/my_file.mp3"}", ...]
```

but should look like:

```
[{mp3: "my_directory/my_file.mp3"}, ...]
```

How could I do this?

Comment: Don't do it that way. Create a plain JavaScript object, and then when it's all finished turn it into JSON with `JSON.stringify()`. Much, much easier (and safer).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Do not push the object as string, rather do it as an object. Change this part where you are sending it:

```
sound_files.push("{mp3: \"my_directory/" + mp3 + "\"}");
```

As an object:

```
sound_files.push({mp3: "my_directory/" + mp3});
```

Comment: Thank you very much! That worked! And I was afraid that I would have to write a regex function :D I will accept your answer because you were the fastest.

Answer (score 2):

Try `sound_files.push({mp3: "my_directory/" + mp3});`

Answer (score 2):

You are currently creating strings that contain the JavaScript source code needed to construct an object.

Just create objects instead.

```
sound_files.push({mp3: "my_directory/" + mp3});
```

Answer (score -1):

To get double quotes add this **+  '"'** and everything will work. But object approach is much clearer way than creating strings.